# Scrolling window with fixed and overlapping background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to reproduce the background image fixed with window scrolling from this website https://ringly.com/.

Can anybody suggest/guide me how can I do this...

Thanks..

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what part you want to reproduce? Is it the slider-background at the top of the page or those colored backgrounds [further down](https://ringly.com/#preorder) at "Connect" and "Customize".

Comment: "Connect" and "Customize" section

Comment: Use parallex effect for this.

Comment: Na..It wouldn't help...I don't know if parallax would work that way...It can be easily done with `background-attachment:fixed`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just using `background-attachment:fixed` with the background images with `position:absolute;` and the parent div with `position:relative`..It took time but figured it how it actually done and got it working... :)

Answer (score 0):

What they're doing is having a extra CSS class 'scroll' on the phone-section, which they remove as soon as you scroll down far enough. So the following CSS property is no longer active and the app-screen stays fixed:

```
.phone-section.scroll .app-screen {
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

If you want to know how they unset and set this 'scroll' CSS class, you need to dig into their minified script that does the magic: https://ringly.com/static/_/js/5612a44f24d4.js 
And search for the term "app-screen". **Tip:** use some [unminify tool](http://unminify.com/) to make it readable.